# Is there a python version of node-webkit

Tags: python, node-webkit

It looks like developing GUI applications in HTML+JS with python in the background would be really nice.  I see node-webkit.  I also see that there are python bindings for webkit.  It just seems like it's an order of magnitude more difficult to set up than python/tkinter - and I couldn't find win7 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is Pyjs, is not entirely build to do that, but that's the nearest thing to it I have found.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could be interested by :

[Python WSGI with Node-Webkit](http://blog.infireal.com/wsgi-node-webkit-2014-03.html)